# R function to start new line every n words?

Tags: r, string, function, newline

I want to create an R function that inserts a "\n" after every n words in a string (where n is an argument).

e.g.

```
startstring <- "I like to eat fried potatoes with gravy for dinner."

myfunction(startstring, 4)
```

would give:

```
"I like to eat\nfried potatoes with gravy\nfor dinner."
```

I believe that to do this I need to split the string up into several parts, each n words long, and then paste these together with a separator of "\n". However I do not know how to do the initial splitting step.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: take a look at `strsplit()` in Base R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could solve this with regular expressions, or with this abomination:

```
words = strsplit(startstring, ' ')[[1L]]
splits = cut(seq_along(words), breaks = seq(0L, length(words) + 4L, by = 4L))
paste(lapply(split(words, splits), paste, collapse = ' '), collapse = '\n')
```

But a better way for most *practical* applications is to use `strwrap` to wrap the text at a given column length, rather than by word count:

```
paste(strwrap(startstring, 20), collapse = '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually more useful for what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` to create an R *function* that inserts a `\n` after every n words, where n is an argument.

```
fun <- function(str, n) {gsub(paste0("([^ ]+( +[^ ]+){",n-1,"}) +"),
                              "\\1\n", str)}
fun(startstring, 4)
#[1] "I like to eat\nfried potatoes with gravy\nfor dinner."
fun(startstring, 2)
#[1] "I like\nto eat\nfried potatoes\nwith gravy\nfor dinner."
```

Where `[^ ]+` matches everything but not a space with a length of at least one. `( +[^ ]+){3}` matches at least one spache  `+` followed by at least one not space `[^ ]+` which will in this case be repeated 3 times `{3}`.

Or an alternative using `\\K` in the pattern instead of `\\1` in x:

```
fun <- function(str, n) {gsub(paste0("[^ ]+( +[^ ]+){",n-1,"}\\K +"),
                              "\n", str, perl=TRUE)}
```

or by using `strsplit`:

```
fun2 <- function(str, n) {
  paste0(strsplit(str, " +")[[1L]], c(rep(" ",n-1),"\n"), collapse = "")}
fun2(startstring, 4)
#[1] "I like to eat\nfried potatoes with gravy\nfor dinner. "
```

or without a space or `\n` in the end:

```
fun3 <- function(str, n) {
  . <- strsplit(str, " +")[[1L]]
  paste0(., c(rep_len(c(rep(" ",n-1),"\n"), length(.)-1), ""), collapse = "")}
fun3(startstring, 4)
#[1] "I like to eat\nfried potatoes with gravy\nfor dinner."
```

Or keeping the matched words using `\K` also in `strsplit`:

```
fun4 <- function(str, n) {paste(strsplit(str,
   paste0("[^ ]+( +[^ ]+){",n-1,"}\\K +"), perl=TRUE)[[1L]], collapse="\n")}
fun4(startstring, 4)
#[1] "I like to eat\nfried potatoes with gravy\nfor dinner."
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code:

```
gsub("([a-z0-9]* [a-z0-9]* [a-z0-9]* [a-z0-9]*) ", "\\1\n", startstring)
```

Comment: looks like I took the same approach as you, Took me a little bit to realise that it only works properly with the trailing space after the last 'word'.

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer, based on OPs desired output, that trailing space should be outside the brackets.

Comment: Yes you are right brother..... @DanielO Thanks.. Have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This uses spaces to seperate words, in `Base-R`

```
gsub("(\\S* \\S* \\S* \\S*) ","\\1\n",startstring) 
[1] "I like to eat\nfried potatoes with gravy\nfor dinner."
```